# Container.GetInstance(Type) when using WcfOperationLifestyle throws ActivationException

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a WebAPI service using SimpleInjector. I have this set up using `AsyncScopedLifestyle` for my scoped dependencies, and one of these dependencies is my Entity Framework `DataContext`. Many things in my service depend on the `DataContext`, and it is generally injected in to my MediatR handlers using constructor injection - this works well. Separately I have a few areas where I need to create an instance of an object given its type (as a string), so I have created a custom activator class (`ResolvingActivator`) that is configured with a reference to `Container.GetInstance(Type)`:

In my container bootstrap code:

```
ResolvingActivator.Configure(container.GetInstance);
```

I can then create objects by using methods such as:

```
ResolvingActivator.CreateInstance<T>(typeName)
```

When I'm using WebAPI, the above is working perfectly.

---

A further part of the project is a legacy API that uses WCF. I have implemented this as a translation layer, where I translate old message formats to new message formats and then dispatch the messages to the Mediator; I then translate the responses (in new format) back to old format and return those to the caller. Because I need access to the Mediator in my WCF services, I'm injecting this in their constructors, and using the `SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf` package to let SimpleInjector's supplied `SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory` build instances of the services. I've also created a hybrid lifestyle, so I can use the same container for my both my WebAPI and WCF services:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
            new AsyncScopedLifestyle(),
            new WcfOperationLifestyle());
```

This works well for some calls, but when a call ultimately calls my `ResolvingActivator` class, I get an `ActivationException` thrown, with the following message:

> The DataContext is registered as 'Hybrid Async Scoped / WCF Operation' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Hybrid Async Scoped / WCF Operation) scope.

As I only receive this error when making WCF calls, I'm wondering if I have something wrong in my configuration. In a nutshell, this will work:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly DataContext db;

    public SomeClass(DataContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public bool SomeMethod() => this.db.Table.Any();
}
```

But this will not:

```
public class SomeClass
{    
    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        // Code behind is calling container.GetInstance(typeof(DataContext))
        var db = ResolvingActivator.CreateInstance<DataContext>();

        return db.Table.Any();
    }
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Edit: here is the stack trace from the `ActivationException`:

```
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1 registration)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1 registration, Scope scope)
   at SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration`1.GetInstance(Scope scope)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Service.Core.ResolvingActivator.CreateInstance(Type type) in Service.Core\ResolvingActivator.cs:line 43
   at Service.Core.ResolvingActivator.CreateInstance(String typeName) in Service.Core\ResolvingActivator.cs:line 35
   at Service.Core.ResolvingActivator.CreateInstance[TService](String typeName) in Service.Core\ResolvingActivator.cs:line 69
```

With a full stack trace here: https://pastebin.com/0WkyHGKv

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: It seems like there is an active scope during the time the object graph gets resolved, but that scope is gone when calling `SomeMethod`. This is troublesome, because that might also mean that injected scoped instances, such as `DataContext` are disposed at that point.

Comment: Stack trace is now in the OP

Comment: I've fleshed that out with the inner exception too. The exception is an `ActivationException` with another nested `ActivationException`

Comment: That's still not the complete stack trace. It is very interesting to see the stack trace up to the start of the request, because that shows in which context the application is running and show a lot what is happening. So I expect WCF related stuff in that stack trace.

Comment: Apologies, OP updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After close inspection of the stack trace, I can conclude what's going on: async.

The `WcfOperationLifestyle` under the covers depends on WCF's `OperationContext.Current` property, but this property has a thread-affinity and doesn't flow with async operations. This is something that has to be fixed in the integration library for Simple Injector; it simply doesn't support async at the moment.

Instead, wrap a decorator around your handlers that start and end a new async scope. This prevents you from having to use the `WcfOperationLifestyle` all together. Take a look at the `ThreadScopedCommandHandlerProxy<T>` implementation [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#decorators-with-func-t-decoratee-factories) to get an idea how to do this (but use `AsyncScopedLifestyle` instead).